# Firebase Realtime DB - getting specific data from array?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have a FB realtime database and I am querying part of it.

```
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "developer")
    databaseRef.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
    snapshot.children.forEach({ (child) in
        print(child)
    })
 }
```

This prints the following:

```
Snap (0) {
    email = "foo@bar.com";
    id = 1;
    image = "dolecki.png";
    name = "Mr. Dolecki";
}
Snap (1) {
    email = "foo@bar.com";
    id = 2;
    image = "bourque.png";
    name = "Mr. Bourque";
}
Snap (2) {
    email = "foo@bar.com";
    id = 3;
    image = "shaw.png";
    name = "Mr. Shaw";
}
```

How can I pull out the bits I'd like out of these (such as each name, id, etc.)? I can't cast to a dictionary because I get an error stating it's coming as an array.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it now.

```
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "developer")
    databaseRef.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot.childrenCount) //3
        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshot {

                if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                    if let name = postDict["name"] {
                        print(name)
                    }
                    //print(postDict.keys) // name, email, id, image
                } else {
                    print("Failed to convert.")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```